# Can confidence intervals be found for the difference in marginal probabilities from two different logistic models of the same sample?

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, marginal-effect

So, I have two multivariable logistic regressions for the same sample. They differ in one independent variable: Model A has a dummy variable for membership in the top 50% (compared to the bottom 50%) of X, and Model B had a DV for membership in the top 25% (compared to the bottom 75%). The other control variables are the same.

I presented my results as marginal estimated probabilities for these dummy variables with 95% confidence intervals, keeping other variables at their means. A reviewer wants me to present the *difference* in marginal probabilities between the models with confidence intervals. Is it possible to create confidence intervals for a difference in marginal estimates for separate models? Or can I only compare logit models by making Relative Risk Ratios or by using Y-standardization for the coefficients?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! There are always bootstrap approaches, but my concern is that you're needlessly dichotomizing that $X$ instead of taking the raw values of $X$. Such an approach literally destroys information and puts you in a position to consider the $49th$ percentile of $X$ less like the $51st$ percentile of $X$ than the $1st$ percentile of $X$.

Comment: @Dave hi, thank you for the welcome! The design of these models was to specifically test the hypothesis that indeed there are threshold values of *X* that determine whether X has an effect. So the full experiment has models using membership in different stratum of X to see of the effect differs from simply having X>0. In other words, it wasn't unreasonable to believe a priori that the effect of X on the dependent variable followed different relationships for different levels of X.